# if compare doesn't work in php

Tags: php, if-statement, compare

I have a problem with a comparation. I execute this code after execute `nmap` and saving the `pid` in the database:

```
include("classes/database.php"); //conection to database

$selectActual = "SELECT * from InfActual";
$resultActual = $conn->query($selectActual);
if ($resultActual->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($rowActual = $resultActual->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "pid in DB: " . $rowActual['pid'] . "<br>";

        echo "................<br>";

        exec("pgrep -l 'nmap' | cut -d' ' -f1 > pids.txt");

        $fh = fopen('pids.txt', 'r');

        while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
            if ($line == $rowActual['pid']) {
                echo "pid in pids.txt: " . $line . " and pid in DB: " . $rowActual['pid'] . " are the same <br>";
            } else {
                echo "pid in pids.txt: " . $line . " and pid in DB: " . $rowActual['pid'] . " are NOT the same <br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
fclose($fh);
```

and this is the result:

```
pid in DB: 5926
................
pid in pids.txt: 5926 and pid in DB: 5926 are NOT the same
```

Why does it tell me that are not the same? I don't understand.
Thank you in advance.

**[SOLVED]**

```
if (intval($line) == intval($rowActual['pid']))
```

Comment: The problem is probably, because you have a new line character (`\n`) at the end of each line in your text file. So: `"xy\n" === "xy"` won't be the same as you might see. (Solution? Just `trim()` your line from the file, e.g. `if (trim($line) == $rowActual['pid'])`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try like:

```
if (intval($line) == intval($rowActual['pid'])) {...}
```

There may be some unwanted characters in the data while reading from file.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to compare, Sanjay's answer is what you need. But if you want to format the data I would suggest using `trim` which will strip any characters or whitespace from the value.

```
while...

$line = trim($line);
$rowActual['pid'] = trim($rowActual['pid']);

if ($line == $rowActual['pid']) {...}
```